# Noise injection to fight overfitting

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I've been researching the specifics of adding noise injection to my input layer to fight against overfitting.  It seems as though most papers recommend a Gaussian noise vector with mean of 0 and a "small" variance, to be applied either additively or multiplicatively to the input layer.  Is this the current convention for noise injection, or is there some other resource I can be pointed towards?

Comment: 1. Can you add some more context?  Input layer of what?  What do you mean by noise injection?  Are you talking about the initial value of the weights, or talking about perturbing the inputs supplied to ML classifier?  I encourage you to edit the question to clarify.  2. What reading have you done?  Where have you looked?  Have you looked at the Stanford class on machine learning, for instance?

Comment: I've made some experiments with adding noise to my input to augment my dataset / make it more robust to minor modifications. It was not worth it. At best, it didn't improve the network. At worst, it made the network much worse. However, you should say which kind of network / which kind of application you have.